# Selenium: Using explicit waits in loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is how you normally implement explicit waits for an element:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```

On the above example it uses the element's ID to search for the element and wait for it to be clickable.

I want to use an existing element object instead of it's selector to add explicit waits.

Example:

```
fields = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input")
for field in fields:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(field))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is just using `visibility_of` instead of `element_to_be_clickable`.

If you really need `element_to_be_clickable` (check that element is visible and enable) then you can do something like that:

```
class enable_of(object):
    def __init__(self, element):
        self.element = element

    def __call__(self, ignored):
        return self.element.is_enabled()


fields = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
for field in fields:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of(field))
    wait.until(enable_of(field))
```